# PHP parsing json_decode outputting nothing

Tags: php, json

This code is supposed to return the value of `/architecture/building_occupant/buildings_occupied` from the Json Freebase file, but it doesn't do anything.

```
   <?php
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/barack_obama?filter=all";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = str_replace('/', 'www', $json);
    $json = str_replace('_', 'www', $json);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    echo $data->property->wwwarchitecturewwwbuildingwwwoccupantwwwbuildingswwwoccupied->values->text;
    ?>
```

I don't seem to get an error message, either...

please assist, and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the object as an array !  You should change your statement like this.

```
$data = json_decode($json); //<--- Remove the TRUE , Adding TRUE will turn it into an array.
```

Comment: I've done many a dumb things in my life, but this might be the dumbest. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @user55335 and this is just funny... `wwwarchitecturewwwbuildingwwwoccupantwwwbuildingswwwoccupied `

Comment: I know it is, I'm just quickly (dirtily) trying to test something, though I know there is never an excuse for fugly code :) @jycr753

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is an array when you use `json_decode($json, TRUE)`

Use:

```
$data['property']['wwwarchitecturewwwbuildingwwwoccupantwwwbuildingswwwoccupied']['values']['text']
```

to output the data